# Nginx is slow... or I'm missing something?

Tags: nginx

I've got a fastcgi applicaiton served by nginx. The site configuration is very basic:

```
upstream foo {
    server unix:/var/run/fastcgi/foo.sock; 
}

server {
  listen 8080;
  server_name _;

  root /usr/share/nginx/www;
  index index.html index.htm;

  location / {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass foo;
  }
}
```

The app itself is quite fast, it's processing typical request in about 3-5 miliseconds - I can see this in the app log and in $upstream_response_time logged to access.log (this is not static files or anything like this, the app is just processing normal HTTP POSTs and returning application/json http response). However, total request time ($request_time variable) is very long, it's 140-160 miliseconds.

What's nginx doing that takes so much time? I suspect it might be opening/closing socket connection for each request or something like this (but 140 miliseconds?!?), how can I trace the cause of the issue?

Comment: try to test nginx alone. I would add a location /test { empty_gif ;}, and test it with apache benchmark. Then you can tel if it is Nginx per se, or Nginx + your app.